# Set default database and also still be able to access other in odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I had two databas with name : 2022 and 2023
when id add this filter in odoo 13 config file :
db_name = 2023
and with out adding dbfilter

but i cant select db 2022 from /web/database/manager
and only can see 2023 db